# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, bubblesort

Tags: python

Понимаю, что проблема очень простая, но не могу найти решение.

```
import random

values = []
temp = 0

print("Enter number of random values")
for i in range(5):
  valuesRandom = random.randrange(0,100)
  values.append(valuesRandom)
  print(values)
  for j in range(5):
    if values[i][j] > values[i+1][j+1]:
      temp = values[i][j]
      values[i][j] = values[i+1][j+1]
      values[i+1][j+1] = temp
```

Уверен что ошибка в том, что я к переменной int обращаюсь как к списку. В паскале такое возможно было провернуть, а как решить ошибку в python?

Comment: Не понял, можете на моем примере описать Ваш код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220702/error-int-object-is-not-subscriptable-python

Comment: А что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать таким образом? Я с паскалем не знаком, поэтому для меня вообще не очевидно, какого поведения вы ожидаете, когда пытаетесь использовать отдельное число как список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

values = []
temp = 0

print("Enter number of random values")
for i in range(5):
    valuesRandom = random.randrange(0,100)
    values.append(valuesRandom)
    print(values)
```

После выполнения данного кода мы получим такой вывод:

```
Enter number of random values
[41]                   
[41, 77]
[41, 77, 73]
[41, 77, 73, 35]
[41, 77, 73, 35, 12]
```

Далее вы зачем-то добавляете ещё один цикл. Я предположил, что вы не совсем понимаете как работают вложенные циклы. 
Вот пример кода:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    print('\nИТЕРАЦИЯ ЦИКЛА')
    print('Текущий элемент: ', i)
    for j in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
        print('ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА')
        print('Текущий элемент (вложки): ', j)

        print(f'{i}:{j}')
```

Вывод:
$ python a.py

```
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент:  1
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  A
1:A
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  B
1:B
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  C
1:C
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  D
1:D
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  E
1:E

ИТЕРАЦИЯ ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент:  2
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  A
2:A
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  B
2:B
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  C
2:C
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  D
2:D
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  E
2:E

ИТЕРАЦИЯ ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент:  3
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  A
3:A
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  B
3:B
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  C
3:C
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  D
3:D
ИТЕРАЦИЯ ВЛОЖЕННОГО ЦИКЛА
Текущий элемент (вложки):  E
3:E
```

Теперь в вашем коде:

```
import random

values = []
temp = 0

print("Enter number of random values")
for i in range(5):
    valuesRandom = random.randrange(0,100)
    values.append(valuesRandom)
    print(values)
    for j in range(5):
        if values[i][j] > values[i+1][j+1]: #Тут и ошибка в индексирование, ведь оно 
            temp = values[i][j] # предназначено для последовательностей
            values[i][j] = values[i+1][j+1] # values[i] вернет целочисленное.
            values[i+1][j+1] = temp # целочисленное нельзя индексировать.
```

**Пример кода по теме "Индексирование":**

```
l1 = [1, 50, 100, [25, 30], 75, 899, 'word', ['first element of nested list', 'the second'], {'key': ('value1', 'value2')}]

a = l1[0]

b = l1[3][0] # l1[3] вернет [25, 30]

c = l1[6]

d = l1 [7][1][4:-1:2] # l1[7][1] вернет 'the second' | а 'the second'[4:-1:2] Это отдельная тема: форматирование строк (срезы)

dict_keys = l1[-1].keys()

dict_value = l1[-1]['key'][0]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(dict_keys)
print(dict_value)
```

Вывод:

```
$ python a.py
1
25
word
scn
dict_keys(['key'])
value1
```

**Если бы я знал, что вы хотите сделать в своём коде, я бы написал решение.
Но думаю теперь вы как минимум освоите тему индексирование.
*Самое основное , про что вам и пишет интерпретатор (TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, bubblesort), это то что вы пытаетесь индексировать числа (integer), а этого делать нельзя***

Comment: Спасибо большое за такое детальное объяснение и за потраченное время :)

Answer (score 3):

Вы делаете что-то очень странное:

```py
valuesRandom = random.randrange(0,100)
  values.append(valuesRandom)
  print(values)
  for j in range(5):
    if values[i][j] > values[i+1][j+1]:
```

Вы получаете случайное число и добавляете его в список. После чего получаете это число через `values[i]` и пытаетесь в цикле обратиться к его индексам от 1 до 5... Конечно, это не работает. Не знаю, чего Вы ожидали.

Вот реализация сортировки "пузырьком":

```py
import random


li = [random.randint(10, 99) for _ in range(10)]
print(li)

is_sorted = False
while not is_sorted:
    is_sorted = True
    for i in range(len(li) - 1):
        if li[i] > li[i+1]:
            is_sorted = False
            li[i], li[i+1] = li[i+1], li[i]
print(li)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!